# MYSQL query, remove row if two columns are null

Tags: mysql

I have a query that shows results like this:

```
Zip   |  Left Price | Right Price
17901 | 100.00      | null
17820 | null        | 40.00
54353 | null        | null
53133 | 40.00       | 542.00
```

How can I remove the results that have both left and price prices as null.  So I wouldn't want the one here with zip 54353 to even show up in the results.

Here's how I did my query:

```
SELECT contacts.zip, CASE WHEN 
 left_return_date IS NULL AND left_delivery_date IS NOT NULL AND left_price 
 IS NOT NULL THEN left_price ELSE null END AS left_price, CASE WHEN 
 right_return_date IS NULL AND right_delivery_date IS NOT NULL AND 
 right_price IS NOT NULL THEN right_price ELSE null END AS right_price
FROM invoice_hearing_aids
LEFT JOIN invoices ON invoices.ID = invoice_hearing_aids.invoice_id
LEFT JOIN contacts ON contacts.id = invoices.contact_id
WHERE 
 trial_complete = 'Y'
 AND invoices.company_id = '1'
 AND invoices.date_issued >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Comment: what is an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `HAVING` clause in the end, like this:

```
SELECT contacts.zip, CASE WHEN 
 left_return_date IS NULL AND left_delivery_date IS NOT NULL AND left_price 
 IS NOT NULL THEN left_price ELSE null END AS left_price, CASE WHEN 
 right_return_date IS NULL AND right_delivery_date IS NOT NULL AND 
 right_price IS NOT NULL THEN right_price ELSE null END AS right_price
FROM invoice_hearing_aids
LEFT JOIN invoices ON invoices.ID = invoice_hearing_aids.invoice_id
LEFT JOIN contacts ON contacts.id = invoices.contact_id
WHERE 
 trial_complete = 'Y'
 AND invoices.company_id = '1'
 AND invoices.date_issued >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
HAVING
  right_price IS NOT NULL OR left_price IS NOT NULL
```

This would work fine if you have relatively small number of such unwanted records (I'd do this for up to 50% of total result set size). If there are more such records, then I'd looks closer into the query and most likely will modify the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Do the afct that left_price and right_price are column values  you could adda where condition

```
   SELECT contacts.zip, 
      CASE WHEN  left_return_date IS NULL 
            AND left_delivery_date IS NOT NULL 
            AND left_price IS NOT NULL THEN left_price 
          ELSE null END AS left_price, 
      CASE WHEN right_return_date IS NULL 
            AND right_delivery_date IS NOT NULL
            AND right_price IS NOT NULL THEN right_price 
          ELSE null END AS right_price
  FROM invoice_hearing_aids
  LEFT JOIN invoices ON invoices.ID = invoice_hearing_aids.invoice_id
  LEFT JOIN contacts ON contacts.id = invoices.contact_id
  WHERE 
   trial_complete = 'Y'
   AND invoices.company_id = '1'
   AND invoices.date_issued >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
   AND NOT (left_price IS NULL AND right_price IS NULL)
```

Comment: This will not filter out the records if they are not null in the table, but the other conditions in `CASE` make them show as null - for example, when `left_delivery_date` and `right_delivery_date` are null.

Comment: The HAVING condition seemed to work for now.  I just wonder if there's a better way to write my query to avoid using HAVING.  Would that be better? Thanks for the help though.

Comment: if your  data don't need  the filter on result but are correctly selected  with the added  where condition you can use the proposed  query avoid having   condition  .. and so you not select unuseful rows .. but this suggestion depend of you data .. content